# Rows count of Couchbase view subset

Tags: couchbase

When I query some view in Couchbase I get the response that has following structure:

```
{
  "total_rows":100,
  "rows":[...]
}
```

'total_rows' is very useful property that I can use for paging. 
But lets say I select only a subset of view using 'start_key' and 'end_key' and of course I don't know how big this subset will be. 'total_rows' is still the same number (as I understand it's just total of whole view). Is there any easy way to know how many rows was selected in subset?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the in-built reduce function `_count` to get the total count of your query.

Just add `_count` as reduce function for your view. After that, you will need to make two calls to couchbase:

1. In one call, you'll set the query param `reduce=true` (along with either `group=true` or `group_level=n`, depending upon how you're sending your key(s)). This will give you the total count of your filtered rows.
2. In the other call, you'll disable the reduce function with `reduce=false` because you now need the actual rows.

You can find more details about map and reduce at http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-writing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an array count/total/length in whatever language you are using.

For example in PHP:

```
$result = $cb->view("dev_beer", "beer_by_name", array('startkey' => 'O', 'endkey'=>'P'));
echo "total = >>".count($result["rows"])
```

If you're actually wanting to paginate your data then you should use limit and skip:
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-querying-pagination.html

Comment: The problem with this variant is that my subset can be very long. So I can't just count it. And I'm using startKey and startDocumentId for pagination because skip can be really slow on big amount of data.

Comment: Yes, paginating by skip/limit require large scans in most of the databases (and SQL too)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to paginate the view in the efficient way, you actually don't need to specify both start and the end.

Generally it is possible to use startkey/startkey_id and limit. In this case the limit will tell you that the page won't be bigger than known size.

Both cases are described in CouchDB book: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#pagination

> Here is how it works:
>
> 1. Request rows_per_page + 1 rows from the view
> 2. Display rows_per_page rows, store + 1 row as next_startkey and next_startkey_docid
> 3. As page information, keep startkey and next_startkey
> 4. Use the next_* values to create the next link, and use the others to create the previous link